# Compare separate regression analyses on the same data

Tags: regression, confidence-interval

I have a dataset of 15K lines and 23 variables. I did an OLS regression to get the regression coefficients. One of my variables in my dataset is mileage, and I want to control for this variable. I know I can do this with the help of interaction terms, but then I need to make 23 interaction terms for each mileage bin. I want to use a different approach but I don't know if this is allowed.

Can I make 3 separate regression models on different pieces of the data (one for every bin)? Then assess the adjusted R2 for fit, make sure it is stable. Then compare the different coefficients of each regression (making sure the confidence intervals don't overlap). If they don't overlap can I say they differ statistically? And are the coefficients values comparable?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to include mileage in your model. You can add it as a variable (with numerical values) or if you want to have 3 ranges of mileage, make 2 dummy variables for any two ranges of mileage. Third range is the base which you will compare the other two ranges of mileage against.

Comment: Hi Abbas, Thx for your answer. Shouldn't I make a dummy for all 23 variables X 3 mileage bins? I want to know the effect of all the variables on every bin. My goal is not prediction but inference, the value of the coefficients is what mattes to me,

Comment: Is mileage your dependent variable (your variable of interest and you want to see the effect of other variables on mileage)?